# How to call a project in another one by clicking a button (Android_elcipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

Good day everybody , 
I am making a virtual market by android , i make to projects (MAP) , (QR scanner)
but how to integrate them together in one application ?
I need to make 2 buttons in the layout , one of them calls the QR scanner by clicking on it , & the other one calls the Map as well.

so what should i do in steps, please :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of intents.  Check out these links...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/launching-different-applications-from-android-activity-using-intent/

Answer (score 0):

Go project Properties of this two project and set as a Is Library project then go your final project properties in Is library option add this two project then you can able to access this two library project all class and activity.